# SQL 2008 Case within where

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL 2008 server.

I have a table (say Salemen) where one column is the status of the salesman (column is xStatus).

xStatus is null, or 'I' for inactive or 'D' for delete in future.

Need a query where user can designate to see all Salesmen, all statuses or only see active Salesmen.

Am having trouble with the stored procedure query in the Where clause.

Variable is passed to query (`@Action`) designating where to see all statuses (`@Action = 1`) or only active Salesmen (`@Action = 2`).

Pseudo code

```
Select *
From Salesmen
Where
If @Action = 1
select regardless of status
If @Action = 2
only select when xStatus is null
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can be done with `OR` like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SalesMen
WHERE (@Action = 1)
OR (@Action = 2 AND xStatus IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is correct.  I was overthinking or not thinking at all.